# Assemble custom DOM from scratch using Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

I want to test a javascript embed that plays videos and fires some events. This embed is our main deliverable. The best way seems to be to create a DOM from scratch, that would have the JS embed and the subscription to the events, so that when the DOM is loaded, the subscription is already there and I don't miss any events.

Then I would like to play the video from my tests and run the tests on a bunch of different platforms using BrowserStack or similar service.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to assemble the whole DOM using Selenium? Injecting the JS code hasn't worked for me so far, as I still need to somehow execute those scripts after injection.
2. A static HTML file or a `data-scheme` are not an option, because they are static. I need the page to actually load that embedded video when loaded.
3. I'd also prefer not to set up a dedicated service that would only build that page and return it when the tests request it.

Are there any options probably adding a DOM-server to Selenium tests? Has anyone done that?

Comment: To load a customized page, either use the [data scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) with `driver.get` or load any URL and rewrite the page with a script injection with `document.write(...)` or `document.documentElement.innerHTML = ...`.

Comment: @FlorentB. The thing is that it's still going to be a static content. Just like loading an html file from disk. This doesn't work, as the JS needs to pull the video.

Comment: The content will be dynamic if you write a dynamic content.